# jquery regex replace non numeric characters but allow plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$('#target').val($('#target').val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
```

I use the above code to leave only numeric characters in an input value I would also like to allow '+' and '-'.

How would I modify the regex to allow this?

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `-` and `+` in the character class.

```
$('#target').val($('#target').val().replace(/[^-+\d]/g, ""));
```

Comment: thank you to late in the evening for my brain to work properly here

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I use a couple of input classes that I control with jQuery:

```
<input class="intgr">
<input class="nmbr">

 $("input.intgr").keyup(function (e) { // Filter non-digits from input value.
    if (/\D/g.test($(this).val())) $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
});
$("input.nmbr").keyup(function (e) { // Filter non-numeric from input value.
    var tVal=$(this).val();
    if (tVal!="" && isNaN(tVal)){
        tVal=(tVal.substr(0,1).replace(/[^0-9+\.\-]/, '')+tVal.substr(1).replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ''));
        var raVal=tVal.split(".")
        if(raVal.length>2)
            tVal=raVal[0]+"."+raVal.slice(1).join("");
        $(this).val(tVal);
    } 
});
```

**intgr** strips all non-numeric

**nmbr** accepts `+`, `-`, `.` and 0-9. The rest of the string gets stripped of all but 0-9 and the first `.` If you are OK with the `+` and `-` being anywhere, Bamar's solution is perfect, short and sweet. I needed the +/- to be only in the first character position if at all, and only one `.` (i.e. strip out beyond the first period so 2.5.9 would be 2.59)